# How to create dynamic fields in easy admin list page?

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

I am working on easy admin list page. I have fields that depends on database. How could i add dynamic fields in yaml file ? Here season field may repeat depends on database

```
 list:
       title: "test"
       fields:
           - { property: name, label: "name" }
           - { property: season,  label: "season" }
```

Comment: Isn't there anyone to know that?

Answer (score 0):

Add getter in your entity, like this:

```
public functioin getLowerName(): ?string
{
    return mb_strtolower($this->getNmae(), 'utf-8');
}
```

Add virtual field to yaml:

```
- { property: 'lowerName',  label: "Name in lower case" }
```